# Concatenating two moved strings

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

The code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s1 = "hello";
    string s2 = "my";
    string s3 = "world";
    string s4;
    s4 = move(s1) + move(s2) + move(s3);
    cout << "s4(" << s4 << ") = s1(" << s1 << ") + s2(" << s2 << ") + s3(" << s3 << ")"<< endl;
}
```

gives the following output:

```
s4(hellomyworld) = s1() + s2(my) + s3(world)
```

Can you explain what is going on? (Tested with XCode 4.6.1)

EDIT:
I expected to see:
    `s4(hellomyworld) = s1() + s2() + s3()`

Comment: Please get used to describing _what you expected to happen instead_. Your understanding may not be the same as _our_ understanding (and, indeed, because you're here asking a question to resolve your confusion, _it probably is not!_)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you expected `s4(hellomyworld) = s1() + s2() + s3()`.

First of all, movement leaves the source object in "a valid state with an unspecified value" (`[C++11: 21.4.2/2]`) — that is, you can't make any claims about what a string's value will be after you moved from it.

Secondly, `std::move` is a misnomer, in that *it doesn't actually move anything*. Movement is implemented by swapping things around, and there is no guarantee that your `string operator+` does anything of the sort (see jmihalicza's answer for a sample implementation); all `std::move` does is obtain an rvalue reference that *may* be moved from.

`[C++11: 21.4.6.3/1]` says about `std::basic_string& assign(basic_string&& str) noexcept` (which is the function you're really invoking, when you follow all the breadcrumbs from `operator+`) that "a valid implementation is `swap(str)`", but that doesn't mean a swap *has* to occur.

Answer (score 1):

`s4 = move(s1) + move(s2) + move(s3)` is in fact `operator=(s4, operator+(operator+(move(s1), move(s2)), move(s3));`
The implementation of `operator+` is not required to modify its rvalue argument, but is allowed. Presumably the implementation is something like this:

```
string operator+(string&& left, string&& right)
{
   string result(left);
   return result += right;
}
```

where right is only read.

Comment: Why would you create a temporary `result` variable if you are going to return a reference? (note that the standard doesn't return a reference there)

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Allocator>
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY inline
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>
operator+(basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&& __lhs, basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,  _Allocator>&& __rhs)
{
    return _VSTD::move(__lhs.append(__rhs));
}
```

So seems like during the concatenation `__rhs`s stayed unchanged. After all the string is accumulated at s1 the move assignment of s4 emptied s1.